# Network Error (tcp_error) on EC2 AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, web, amazon-ec2

I have a website with Codeigniter and its works perfectly on localhost, but after i upload it to the server and its also works fine but there is one task that catch an Network error message. The error looks like:

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out" The Web Server
>   may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it
>   from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later
>   time.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.

[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcQCD.png)

But if i do the exact same task in local host it show like this

[Localhost success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmbcJ.png)

Im using EC2 with instance t2.micro, do i have to upgrade to the new instance? because i new to AWS and EC2, and im not the one who created it on the first place. Thank you

[EDIT]

Already try upgrading to t t2.2xlarge and still error, i notice this error always happen when the load time is more that 30s, is there any timeout limit in EC2 instance?

Comment: Do you just have a single EC2 instance? Have you verified differences in PHP ini? Does the request make external calls?

Comment: @mokugo-devops only single EC2 instance, the php version is difference, the one in server is version 7.2.16 and in my localhost is version 7.3.6, the request dosent make any external call, but there is a bunch of query and calculation in function api_get_result_jtt